# Scrolling Extension/Feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a scrolling extension or feature in VS Code that allows for "continuous" scrolling between two open tabs of the same file? For example, If the bottom line of the left tab is line 75 then the top line of the right tab would be line 76? And as I scroll in one, it auto scrolls in the other.

Comment: almost identical question here: [Is there a way in VS Code split the screen vertically and sync scroll different at point of the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74156779/11107541)

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)